# How to avoid GORM to create column names in snake case?

Tags: postgresql, go-gorm

I'm using GORM with PostgreSQL and GORM is creating queries with snake case column names by default. With following configuration, it skips generating snake case column names but also It generates mixed column names like I use in struct. I want GORM to create lower case column names but not snake case. How can I do that?

```
db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("gorm.db"), &gorm.Config{
  NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{
    TablePrefix: "t_",   // table name prefix, table for `User` would be `t_users`
    SingularTable: true, // use singular table name, table for `User` would be `user` with this option enabled
    NoLowerCase: true, // skip the snake_casing of names
    NameReplacer: strings.NewReplacer("CID", "Cid"), // use name replacer to change struct/field name before convert it to db name
  },
})
```

Thanks in advance.